# Trailing slash on SPA index without a filename in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I've read through and tried a lot of solutions to this and am not solving the final piece of this puzzle.

I have a Nginx installation with a single subdomain that needs to serve many proxied apps/services.  I want to rewrite one of them while proxy'ing to the back end service to add a directory name. The one that needs a directory name has encoded URLS, query params, and static files. Normally, the service would have a domain ending at / and it also makes calls to /api.

I have...

```
        location /authsrv {
            rewrite ^\/authsrv\/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4593;
        }
```

This, along with modifying the SPA's config behind it to use /authsrv/ as a root URL, works for pre-pending `/authsrv/` to everything in the proxied service, transparently to the service itself.

The only problem is the index, `/authsrv` without the trailing slash on the index of the SPA 404s, presumably because 'nothing' doesn't match the capture group regex in the rewrite.

How can I explicitly add the trailing slash behind `/authserv` while maintaining the rest of the rewrite, even on the index of the SPA where the contents behind the directory are blank?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer when I took a break and thought about it..

```
rewrite ^\/authsrv(.*) /$1 break;
```

Therefore the regex will match whether the trailing slash is present or not. Since the concern is not the regex but rather the capture group after it to get passed to the service/app listening on a root url, the manner in which the leading directory is matched doesn't matter.